# need help to sign out of superuser.com

Tags: support

I am in the habit of properly logging off my online connections.  Where can I do that here on superuser.com?

To adhere to the quality standards of this site, I will not describe what I have already tried:

- I have tried to look for a sign-off link
- I have tried to look for a sign-out link
- I have tried to look within my account for a link to sign-off, sign-out, log-off or log-out.

Answer (score 3):

Click the downward arrow to the left of your screen name on the top of the page and select `log out`

[image]

or navigate to https://superuser.com/users/logout

Comment: Wow... my voting habits as of late suck.

Answer (score 2):

The UI is a little different these days:

[image: Newer SU/SE interface]